# Find the length of string array with strlen()

Tags: c++, string, string.h

I have been trying to find the length of `string` which has an array of `char`s with `strlen()` function but it is not working.
The code I am using is something like this:

```
string s[]={"a","b","c"};
int len = strlen(s.c_str());
```

It produces the following error:

```
"request for member âc_strâ in âwArrayâ, which is of non-class type"
```

But when I have used this `strlen()` function on `string`s before like this, it worked fine:

```
fin.open("input.txt");
string tempStr;
getline(fin, tempStr,'\n');
int len = strlen(tempStr.c_str());
```

What I am missing here? I know I can find the length of `string s[]` with

```
int size = sizeof( s ) / sizeof( s[ 0 ] );
```

But why can't I use `strlen()`. Can someone explain what is going on?

Comment: `s` is an array, it has no `c_str` function. is std::vector an option?

Comment: You are missing the fact that `std::string` is not `std::string[]`.

Comment: @Billz
But it works for char type array....???????????/

Comment: @n.m. Then why does it work on tempStr. That is a string as well.

Comment: a string is different from an array of strings.

Comment: You should never use `strlen` in C++ btw; it is a C-ism.

Comment: @manu-fatto thaks a lot......................

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Finding the length of a fixed size array of any type is easy enough with a helper function template:

```
#include <cstddef> // for std::size_t

template< class T, size_t N >
std::size_t length(const T (&)[N] )
{
  return N;
};

string s[]={"a","b","c"};
std::cout << length(s) << std::endl;
```

In C++11, the function would be `constexpr`.

Concerning [strlen](http://en.cppreference.com/w/c/string/byte/strlen), it counts `chars` until it finds a null termination character `\0`. When you call [std::string](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/string/basic_string)'s`c_str()` method, you get a pointer to the first `char` in a null terminated string.

Comment: @juanchopanza Thanks.. But i really need to know why strlen() works on tempStr and not string s. (see code for tempStr and s)

Comment: @AlexChamberlain I didn't remember off the top of my head which header is required for `std::size_t`. Fixed now.

Comment: @DeadCoder I added something about `strlen`.

Answer (score 1):

A C++ way to do it would be using std::vector

```
vector<string> ss;

ss.push_back("a");
ss.push_back("b");
ss.push_back("c");

cout << ss.size(); // number of strings in your vector : 3
```

you can also access each string :

```
cout << ss[0].size(); // 1
```

Answer (score 0):

it must be like :

```
string s[]={"a","b","c"};  //array of string
for(auto i:s){
int len = strlen(i.c_str());  because you need to convert one string to c type string
cout<<len<<" ";
}
```

to get the array length :

```
std::array<int> nums {1, 3, 5, 7};

std::cout << "nums contains " << nums.size() << " elements.\n";
```

http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/container/array/size

`strlen()` accepts `ctype` strings. and `c_str()` convert the `string`(STL) to `ctype` string(Null terminated) which is accepted by strlen.

Comment: @Arpit of course it is 1, Every element of the array has length 1.

Comment: so this is what to be expected.

Comment: @juanchopanza we understand the ques. differently . you work on array and i work on individual string.

Comment: Sorry, that comment was meant to be for @DeadCoder.

Comment: @juanchopanza Just last thing. What is difference between ctype string and string ????

Comment: @Arpit same question as asked to Juanchopanza

Comment: @DeadCoder "ctype" string would be this null-terminated sequence of `char` I was talking about. `string` would be `std::string`, the standard C++ string class with lots of useful functionality.

Answer (score 0):

the define of strlen: size_t strlen ( const char * str ), note the type of input parameter.
you define string s[]={"a","b","c"}; which is an **array**, so the following statement will work:
strlen(s[0].c_str());
In addition, to calculate the length of **array** s, sizeof( s ) / sizeof( s[ 0 ] ) work only when every element of 's' has the same length.