# How to get last index of a string array in C++

Tags: c++, arrays

I am naive programmer in c++ and just started learning c++ by solving problems.
Please let me know if there is any old link or source where i can get the answer of below question.

I have string array and i need to parse it till the last element but I don't know what condition I will put to check that loop has reached the last element in array.

For example

```
int fun1(string members[]){
    int i=0;
     for(i=0;END_CONDITION;i++){
         /*Do some work*/
     }
}
```

And member is something like this

```
 string members[] = 
 {"BETTY F M A A C C",
  "TOM M F A D C A",
  "SUE F M D D D D",
  "ELLEN F M A A C A",
  "JOE M F A A C A",
  "ED M F A D D A",
  "SALLY F M C D A B",
  "MARGE F M A A C C"};
```

I have tried to search alot to get the answer but i could't find any answer which can help. 
In most of thread guys are saying to use vector instead of string array. But here i am getting argument as string array.

Comment: Add length of array as second parameter for your function

Comment: You could use a `std::array<std::string, n>`, which will have a `size` method.

Comment: If you want to learn C++ use `std::vector` instead of C array `[]`. If you want to learn C do not use `std::string`. If you want to use C++ use at the standard library.

Answer (score 1):

In case of plain array you have to pass the size of array to your function. There's no other option. However, you can use `vector<string>` to make things easier...

Comment: There is not other *good* option for a beginner, but there are other options:  `template <size_t N> int fun1(string (&members)[N]) { ...use N here... }`.  You can also use a sentinel value - e.g. an empty `std::string`.

Answer (score 0):

You can do for individual string - `myStr.length()` it will give you the length of your individual string. `myStr.length() - 1` will be your last element index for a string.

For length of a string array an answer has already been posted on Stack Overflow - [Find the length of string array with strlen()](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14919254/find-the-length-of-string-array-with-strlen)

I use this - `sizeof(myStrArray)/size(myStrArray[0])` to get the length of a string array (i.e. no. of elements) and it works for me. However, you have to be careful if myStrArray is defined with specific linkage scopes e.g. static or extern - this might not work the same way. Also, if you use pointers, this will not be helpful (editd after @MikeSeymour commented on the answer).

This should help you. The other option is to create a vector and store each string element in your vector and you should get the indices out. `myVector.size()` will give you the no. of elements in your string vector and you can work out which is the last element index based on 0-based indexing :)

```
#include <iostream>
using namespace std;

int main() {
    std::string s[] =  
 {"BETTY F M A A C C",
  "TOM M F A D C A",
  "SUE F M D D D D",
  "ELLEN F M A A C A",
  "JOE M F A A C A",
  "ED M F A D D A",
  "SALLY F M C D A B",
  "MARGE F M A A C C"};
  size_t myStrArrLen = 0;

  myStrArrLen = sizeof(s)/sizeof(s[0]);

  cout <<  myStrArrLen << endl;
  cout << s[myStrArrLen - 1].length() << std::endl;

  return 0;
}
```

Does this result show what you wanted to do?

Comment: @ErikAlapää     Does the OP say that he is interested in C-style solution? From the question here, where does the C application come in play?

Comment: No, but a '\0'-terminated string is C-style. And calling it a string array is confusing, a string array is something like std::string string_arr[10], which is seldom used...

Comment: Beware that this `sizeof` malarkey only works on the array itself. If you try it in the function, where you only have a pointer, you'll get the wrong value and weird runtime behaviour.

Comment: @MikeSeymour     +1 for that reminder. The OP was suggested to use a vector<> but he insisted that there should be another way (not necessarily a better way) to do it.

Answer (score 0):

C++ doesn't support any feature to determine the size of an array, unless it is allocated on stack, where `sizeof` may be used. Even with stack allocated array, its size cannot be determined in the function to which it is passed.

You better use `vector`, `list`, or `array` (`array` for compile-time defined array size). Otherwise, keep the counts yourself via some struct, or other variables.

Answer (score 0):

`sizeof(string)` is not been change according to `string::length`.

that's why you can use `sizeof(members)/sizeof(string)`

A complete solution:

```
int main()
{
     string members[] =
     {"BETTY F M A A C C",
      "TOM M F A D C A",
      "SUE F M D D D D",
      "ELLEN F M A A C A",
      "JOE M F A A C A",
      "ED M F A D D A",
      "SALLY F M C D A B",
      "MARGE F M A A C C"};

     cout<<sizeof(members)/sizeof(string)<<endl;
}
```

This will give output: 8

inside the function you can't do so, because in:

```
int fun1(string members[]){
   cout<<sizeof(members)<<endl;
}
```

you'll get size of a pointer, not the size you've got in the upper example.

So you just should add size to your function:

`int fun1(string members[], size_t size)`

And from the main function above you should call it like this:

```
size_t size = sizeof(members)/sizeof(string);
fun1(members,size);
```

Answer (score 0):

You say:

> In most of thread guys are saying to use vector instead of string array. But here i am getting argument as string array.

Can you change what you receive as arguments? Consider these alternatives:

```
int fun1(string members[], std::size_t length){
    for(std::size_t i=0; i < length; i++) {
        /*Do some work*/
    }
}
string members[] = 
{ "BETTY F M A A C C", // ...
  "MARGE F M A A C C" };
fun1(members, 2);
```

Or:

```
template<typename I>
int fun1(I begin, const I& end) {
    for(; begin != end; ++begin)
        /* Do some work with (*begin) */
    }
}
fun1(std::begin(members), std::end(members));
```

Or:

```
int fun1(const std::vector<std::string>& members)
    for(const auto& s: members) {
        // on n-th iteration, s is a const reference to n-th element
    }
}

std::vector<std::string> members = 
{ "BETTY F M A A C C", // ...
  "MARGE F M A A C C" };
fun1(members);
```

Or the same as the last example, with std::array instead of std::vector.